# Currency field in CRM 2011

Tags: checkbox, dynamics-crm-2011, currency

I have a check box and a currency field. When I click on the check box, the field is enabled. The user fills in the dollar amount but when they save the form, an error message pops saying:

```
must provide a value in the currency field
```

However, there is already a value in that field. How can I resolve this?

Comment: is it a require field? Does it have red asterisk on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a currency value field, you must also put the Currency lookup field on the form, and the user must specify a currency (from your installed currencies), so the value makes sense. It sounds like you are filling in the value field, but the Currency lookup.